# f:ajax listener never fired

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, listener

i'm using JSF 2.0 primefaces 2.2 and Spring 3.0.5.
I have a little problem usign f:ajax listener that wasn't fired.
This is the code:

```
<h:form prependId="false" >
   <h:selectOneRadio value="#{autoBean.newAuto.marca}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="aa"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="bb"/>
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{autoBean.update}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

and this is the method:

```
public void update(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
}
```

any idea? 
Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**
Sorry, but the problem isn't simply to explain...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've missed to specify which event you want to trigger the ajax update:

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" ... />
```

Comment: I have restarted my pc and it work.
However, for input text I need to specify event like you suggest.
That code is only an example; I was working with h:selectOneRadio.
However, thank you.

Comment: It uses a default of `valueChange` when used inside `UIInput`. OP also mentioned that `render="aa"` works :) The root cause was just that OP wasn't running the code he think was running.

Comment: sorry, for misunderstanding. I have updated the answer because with selectOneRadio f:ajax doesn't work even if I specify the event.
Using p:ajax it work.