# Mixing Ajax and full requests in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, listener

The JSF code which is giving me problems is the following:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
          <!-- Minimum Password Length -->
          <h:outputText value="#{i18n['xxx']}:" />
                        <h:inputText id="minLength"
                                     value="#{passwordPolicies.minLength.paramValue}"
                                     required="true">
                            <f:validateLongRange minimum="1"/>
                            <f:ajax event="valueChange"
                                    render="@this minLengthMessage"
                                    listener="passwordPolicies.testListener"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message id="minLengthMessage"
                                   for="minLength"
                                   errorClass="error"
                                   tooltip="true"/-->
                <!-- Many other validation fields -->
<h:panelGrid/>
```

Firstly, I am having a very similar issue as: [f:ajax listener never fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900587/fajax-listener-never-fired) . I must combine Ajax and full requests on my JSF page. [Jim Driscoll @ java.net](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/10/01/mixing-ajax-and-full-requests-jsf-20) says that in order for these 2 to work, an Ajax error listener must be set up? Is this very much diferent than the *listener* property of the *ajax* tag?

Now, I know I could try Primefaces p:inputText and p:ajax tags, but these would require me individual listeners for all my fields that are validated. Is there a way to fix the f:ajax error listener, in order to be triggered and dont get the nasty:

[image]

Thanks for any input!

Comment: This should usually not happen when you just tab the fields. The code doesn't give anything away and also the listener is not bound properly, which would have yield a different exception. When exactly do you get this error? When you press a non-Ajax commandbutton?

Comment: Hi, yes, it occurs when I press a non-Ajax button, and it happens randomly, like when the race condition makes the 2 reasons Jim Driscoll mentioned on the link I posted happen.

Comment: Jim tells to use `<f:ajax>` inside commandbutton to fix this issue. The listeners are not mandatory, they were just an example to illustrate the race condition.

Comment: The link to Jim Driscoll's article at java.net no longer exists. I think the same article still exists on [his personal blog](https://jamesgdriscoll.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/mixing-ajax-and-full-requests-in-jsf-2-0/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your command button to fire an ajax request instead.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Those `<f:ajax>` listeners are not mandatory. They were just used as an example in Jim's article to illustrate the race condition. Which get invoked first? Obviously you'd like to invoke the listeners first.

A practical example of almost the same kind of form can be found in [this chapter](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheView) of [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html). Only `blur` is been used instead of `valueChange`, because the `valueChange` won't be invoked when you blur a `required="true"` field which is kept empty which causes that the "Value is required" message will never show up on such a field.

Comment: I have an additional question, is the code snippet you posted here necessary if the commandButton action is leading me to another JSF page? Logically for me its not, but still want to avoid the error that I was having before. Much appreciated!

Comment: Let it send a redirect. `return "outcome?faces-redirect=true";`.

Comment: This is a good solution when the prob is only when we click the button, but what can I do if the user click on a link? Clicking the links triggers a full request and at the same time blur will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Just recording this here for posterity, but creating an error handler in JavaScript and then referencing it from the `f:ajax` tag will suppress the error alert and cause your error handler to be called with the error message instead.  This behavior is described in the article by Jim Driscoll mentioned in the question but not specifically demonstrated.  I've verified that it works:

`function onAjaxError( error ) { console.log( error.description ); }`

`<f:ajax onerror="onAjaxError" ...>`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add some monitor this is how :

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit"  action="#{yourBean.YourAction}" render="thisIsWhereYouWantToDisplay">
<f:ajax onevent="monitor" execute="@form" render="@form" />
                                        </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: I fail to understand how this is an answer to the question