# JSF Ajax Problem

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

My first input on the form has a  tag.

```
<h:inputText id="kotajNumber" label="#{lbls.kotajNumber}" styleClass="ltr" value="#{issuePromise.declaration.kotajNumber}" required="true" style="min-width: 0px; width: 130px;">
   <f:ajax event="blur" render="loader exporter personName nameOfMaterial count materialWeight materialWeight numberOfPackages messageKotajNumber" execute="@this" listener="#{issuePromise.showDeclaration}" onevent="showLoader()" />
</h:inputText>
```

But when I click on a link, the new page is loading while the **ajax** request is sending also and I receive an alert which is saying that I've mixed a **full** request with an **ajax** one!!!

How should I fix it?

[image: The error alert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your link triggers a full request. And if your focus was on the input field before it will mix up with the ajax request from blurring. Maybe you can change the link to make an ajax request instead.

See this [similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262897/mixing-ajax-and-full-requests-in-jsf-2-0)